# Multiple column unique key allows multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with 4 columns

```
Column  Type        Null  Default
----------------------------------
id      int(11)     No    None     AUTO_INCREMENT
col1    int(11)     No    None
col2    int(11)     No    None
col3    varchar(20) Yes   Null
```

I have created a index with col1, col2, col3 since I don't want duplicate rows. I understand that NULL value is considered distinct so the table accepts duplicate rows.

What is the best alternative so I can have rows with unique values for col1, col2, col3?

Comment: You'll still get duplicate erows, since nulls aren't counted in uniqueness decisions for indexes. so two or more records with `(null, 1, 2)` is entirely possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `NOT NULL` on `col3` and set the default value to `''`.

Answer (score 1):

The way I was taught to understand NULL is that NULL is a state and not a value.  So you are not actually having a distinct value with NULL.  I would actually consider using a blank string instead of NULL or setting some other default value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the database to enforce it, there aren't that many options. Since you can't force the database to consider NULL anything except distinct you can either;

- Use the empty string in the column instead of NULL. This will only cause trouble if "" is a valid value and you want it to be distinct from an actual NULL value.
- Use the empty string in the column instead of NULL and add a boolean column that indicates a NULL value. Add that to the unique index too and the database will separate "fake NULL" from empty strings.

Both options will require you to set col3 to NOT NULL and do some mapping of values on insert/select.